# mysql: Descending order of dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql which has value as such:

```
column1   column2         column3
feri      football       12-Mar-2015
feri      football       15-Nov-2017
feri      football       5-Dec-2019
feri      Volley Ball    12-Dec-2018
sugi      football       5-Dec-2018
```

I want to sort them in a Descending order wrt the dates

Expected Result:

```
column1    column2           column3
feri       football         5-Dec-2019
feri       Volley Ball      12-Dec-2018
sugi       football         5-Dec-2018
feri       football         15-Nov-2017
feri       football         12-Mar-2015
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should read about [ORDER BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get column1 and column2 with the biggest value in column3.

```
SELECT column1, column2, MAX(column3)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY column1, column2
```

just like that.

Comment: yes, but I want to show only one data that does not have in common

Comment: looks like i misread your expected result, well you should follow Arun recommendation to read the article.i'll delete my answer later

Comment: addition, this is so basic because you only need to add `ORDER BY column3 DESC` at the back of your query

Comment: What does "data that does not have in common" mean?  Give an example

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```html
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column3 DESC;
```